# How can I change the output format and display all numbers as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def printintersection(arr1,arr2,m,n):
    i,j=0,0
    while i<m and j<n:
        if arr1[i]<arr2[j]:
            i+=1
        elif arr2[j]<arr1[i]:
            j+=1
        else:
            print(arr2[j])
            j+=1
            i+=1
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [3,4,5,6]
m=len(arr1)
n=len(arr2)
printintersection(arr1,arr2,m,n)
```

**

---

I am getting the output as mentioned below.

```
3
4
5
```

and I want the output in the list format i.e.

```
[3,4,5]
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With minimal changes in the above code, you can get the desired result by appending each number to a list, and printing list at the end.

**Snapcode**

```
def printintersection(arr1,arr2,m,n):
    l = []
    i,j=0,0
    while i<m and j<n:
        if arr1[i]<arr2[j]:
            i+=1
        elif arr2[j]<arr1[i]:
            j+=1
        else:
            l.append(arr2[j])
            j+=1
            i+=1
    print(l)

arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [3,4,5,6]
m=len(arr1)
n=len(arr2)
printintersection(arr1,arr2,m,n)
```

But I believe, list comprehension is a much simpler way to accomplish this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [3,4,5,6]
l = [num for num in arr1 if num in arr2]
print(l)
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You are always welcome. Good luck in learning and mastering Python.

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply. Here I can see an issue with this code. if the arr1 has more elements  then it works fine but in case if the arr2 has more elements then it gives incorrect result .

Comment: It's supposed to work fine for both the cases. Can I have an example of a failed case ?